# Camera preview through X11 using --qt-preview not working

Tags: camera, libcamera

Connected from my desktop host via `ssh -X` to my Raspi 3B, I assumed that `libcamera-hello --qt-preview` would create a preview window on my desktop. But it is not. Instead, `Made DRM preview window` is output on the console and the preview is displayed on the HDMI output.

X11 forwarding is active and working (verified this with *xload* from x11-apps).

Piping the outout through netcat as workaround works like a charm (pi: `libcamera-vid -n -t 0 --framerate 25 --output -  | nc 192.168.1.10 5001`, desktop: `nc -l -v -p 5001 | mplayer -fps 30 -cache 512 -`).

Any suggestions to identify the problem?

OS: Raspberry Pi OS bullseye 64bit lite, Raspi 3B, Camera: ov5647, libcamera-apps-lite version git20230301+54a781d, libcamera0 version git20230302+923f5d70-1.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a known issue; it's to do with the relationship between the X server and the GPU.  The latter is passing the camera output directly to HDMI, and the former isn't literally scraping or mirroring a local GUI session.